# while using this line use fields __PACKAGE__->SUPER::_praveen, qw(path); getting error SUPER.pm not found

Tags: perl, scripting, field, super

```
use fields __PACKAGE__->SUPER::_praveen, qw(path);
```

while executing above line with perl_5.18.2 getting an error @INC SUPER.pm not found.
I am able to compile above line with Perl 5.8.8
can  you please help me on this

Comment: You will have to give more information. Please [edit] your question and tell us what you are doing, in which context you are working and with what modules.

Answer (score 1):

That error shouldn't be produced by that line since the only module loaded by that line is `fields.pm`. Unsurprisingly, I can't replicate your error.

`Foo.pm`:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
sub _praveen { qw( id ) }
1;
```

`Bar.pm`:

```
package Bar;
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use parent 'Foo';
use fields __PACKAGE__->SUPER::_praveen, qw( path );
1;
```

`a.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
use Bar qw( );
say "ok";
```

Output:

```
$ perlbrew use 5.18.2t

$ perl a.pl
ok
```

Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised you're getting errors: the `fields` pragma expects a list of field names as parameters, and even if the inherited class provides something suitable through a call like that, it is far from clear whether the superior class is in scope at that point.

If you want more help then you must show a minimal code sample that reproduces the issue.